# How can Nyquist Frequency increase SNR?

Tags: snr

I am busy with Dynamic Range of an ADC including Programmable Gain Atmplifier. I try to calculate maximum Dynamic range level of my measurement system. How can i calculate Dynamic range? I have read these equations: 
"SNR (dB) = 6.02x(ENOB) + 1.76 (dB)"   ENOB: (efficient number of bits) also
total DR can be found by this formula; DR = SNR of ADC (dB) + Gain of PGA (dB)" According to these formulas where is the nyquist frequency? I don't understand how can Nyquist Frequency increase SNR? Can anyone explain me?

Comment: ENOB is effective number of bits

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually mean how can increasing the sampling rate (and by inference the nyquist rate) increase the resolution of an ADC.

I also think you meant SNR(dB) = 6.02 N + 1.76 rather than 6.02ENOB + 1.76.

Just going thru the errors in your question....

Dynamic range has also nothing to do with gain - it has everything to do with the bandwidth of your signal, the ADC sampling rate and the ADC bit-resolution. For instance, if the BW of your signal is 20 kHz the minimum sampling rate is 40kHz but, if you over sample by 4 (160 kHz) then you effectively increase the resolution of your ADC by 1 bit. Oversample by 4 times again and you retrieve another bit of resolution. This is basically the theory behind sigma delta ADCs but applies equally to any ADC.

I'd urge you to read [this](http://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-003.pdf) document by analog Devices entitled "Understand SINAD, ENOB, SNR, THD, THD + N, and SFDR so You Don't Get Lost in the Noise Floor".